# Conditionally rendering a React/Material UI className according to state variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, conditional-statements, styling

I am using React and Material UI to create a basic navbar setup, because React-Router-Dom does not want to work inside this project, and would be overkill for what I am doing.  When I click the a button, it is setting the menuItems id as the value of the activeView. I am trying to conditionally change the className of the button to active (like this: className={classes.active} ), so I can access the Material UI styling class active.  I tried a solution I found in another questions, but it does want to work for me. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Currently it does appear to be able to find the 'active' class, giving me this error "Cannot find name 'active'.ts(2304)".  I even tried to create the className 2 different ways.

Material UI Class in NavBarStyling.tsx

```
nav: {
   <--removed, not relevant-->
    },
    '& button.active': {
      color: '#dadad8',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
  },
  active: {
      color: '#dadad8',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
```

Setting state in main App

```
const [activeView, setActiveView] = React.useState(1);
```

Navbar.tsx

```
import { useNavStyles } from './NavBarStyling';

const classes = useNavStyles();

const NavBar = () => {
  return(
    <div className={classes.nav}>
      {menuItems.map((menuItems: { id: number; label: string; }) => (
        <Button key={menuItems.id} onClick={() => setActiveView(menuItems.id)}
            className={classes[`${activeView === menuItems.id ? active : ''}`]}
        >
          {menuItems.label}
        </Button>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: What is the `classes` object?

Comment: the classes object is was created to utilize the Material UI styling.  I updated the code above to show that is going on there

Answer (score 0):

Here is your error `` className={classes[`${activeView === menuItems.id ? active : ''}`]} ``

You need to return `active` as a string and not a variable
`className={classes[activeView===menuItems.id?'active':'']}`

or like this
`className={activeView===menuItems.id?classes.active:''}`